# Can I make check valve in simple workshop?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, fluid-mechanics, hydraulics, valves

I need a check valve ( one way valve ) for my project which has less actuation force (IDK real term. shouldn't require high pressure for inflow of fluid) and I searched in market for the valve but couldn't find one. Also I am not in place where I can easily order online.

I saw an hydraulic (can hold 2 tons ~ 7k psi. I need about 500 psi only though.) with ball valve that lifts when inflow and gets down to its seat due to gravity. It is really simple with no spring and also has no rubber or anything like that to prevent seepage of oil but it works. So I was thinking if I can make one in lathe?

There are two problems for that:

- how to make a spherical hole.
- despite making the structure how can I be sure that it won't leak.
  Like theoretically it is possible but mostly somehow the products
  don't turn out okay as planned.

I am also thinking instead of ball, a tapered one will be easier to manufacture but not sure if it will work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Very easy to make if you have even basic machining skills. Use a ball end mill of the same size as the ball bearing, held in the lathe tail chuck. If you have micro-grooving tools, a recess can be cut for an O ring to improve the seal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

*Figure 1. A sprung check-valve using a ball and a taper. Source: [Cross Controls](http://crosscontrols.com/product/walworth-api-602-ball-check-valve/)*

I'm no machinist but it seems to me that a purchased ball (a bearing, for example) should make a good fit into a well machined tapered hole. If operating with gravity assist the spring may be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Spring-loaded ball check valve, you have described it, now you need to make it and that is down to the precision you are capable of.